# What are graduate school admission "clearing rounds" and start dates?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding, deadlines, hong-kong

I'm finishing my honours degree this November, and would like to apply to do a PhD in Hong Kong. One problem I'm having is trying to understand the start dates. For instance, they have three application deadline dates:

1. Main round: September 1 - December 1
2. 1st clearing round: December 2 - April 30
3. 2nd clearing round: May 1 - August 31

What does the "clearing rounds" mean exactly? Also, if I apply to do a PhD before the deadline, relatively how soon would it be to get an acceptance/rejection?

People who apply in December 1 deadline for the Hong Kong government funded PhD fellowship don't get an answer until March. I don't know if this applies to PhD admission though as it doesn't say when you hear back on that, and I don't really want to wait until March, find I've been rejected, and I'm now unable to enroll in a masters program in my country as the trimester has already begun.

This is all confusing to me and I'd like some advice on the general admission time line for PhD applicants.

Comment: Wunderful question!